Chakra ui typescript enforces aria-label for icon-button - how to turn off
So I have a Chakra UI icon button
<IconButton
   aria-label="Left Arrow"

And I want to remove the aria-label - why would I want to do that? Because the IconButton is inside an aria-hidden section of the tree, and as such the label is superfluous.
But if I remove it I get the following typescript complaints
 ../../node_modules/@chakra-ui/button/dist/icon-button.d.ts:23:5
web:tsc:     23     "aria-label": string;
web:tsc:            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
web:tsc:     '"aria-label"' is declared here.

How can I make a chakra icon button without giving it an unnecessary aria-label.

my recommendation: Simply keep the label, but make it clear in the code that it’s irrelevant: `aria-label="irrelevant, this is inside a hidden subtree”. That way, in the future, you have a documentation of why you skipped the mandatory attribute

yeah I considered that but it also offends my sense of propriety and order.

Let's have a look at the source code for the <IconButton />?
"use client"

import { forwardRef } from "react"
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "./button"

export interface IconButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  /**
   * A11y: A label that describes the button
   */
  "aria-label": string
}

/**
 * Icon button renders an icon within a button.
 *
 * @see Docs https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/icon-button
 */
export const IconButton = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, IconButtonProps>(
  function IconButton(props, ref) {
    return <Button padding="0" ref={ref} {...props} />
  },
)

IconButton.displayName = "IconButton"


Essentially, IconButton is just a Button with one mandatory extra prop aria-label and enforced padding=0. As you can see it does not have it's own variants, or styles, or anything. So, if you don't like aria-label you can simply use Button with padding=0.

thanks I think this is probably the best solution, under the circumstances.

Do it by using TypeScript's utility types to override the type declaration of the aria-label attribute for the IconButton component
import { IconButton } from "@chakra-ui/react";

// Define a type to represent the props of IconButton without aria-label
type IconButtonWithoutAriaLabelProps = Omit<React.ComponentProps<typeof IconButton>, "aria-label">;

// Define a new component based on IconButton but without aria-label
const IconButtonWithoutAriaLabel: React.FC<IconButtonWithoutAriaLabelProps> = (props) => {
  // Render IconButton without passing aria-label prop
  return <IconButton {...props} />;
};

export default IconButtonWithoutAriaLabel;


does not work, because "aria-label" is still missing for underlying <IconButton /> component (depends on typescript/eslint settings). Refs not forrwarded

For accessibility purpose aria-label is an important property a developer should use. As per official ChakraUI documentation, aria-label is an mandatory prop and you've to pass it.
Doc: https://v2.chakra-ui.com/docs/components/icon-button#usage

as I noted it is inside an aria-hidden div, in my opinion an aria-label on an element inside an aria-hidden div is a really unimportant property and a developer should not use it.
